# Log Rotation in laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, log-rotation

I have a project that is in laravel 4.1. My `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` in production has gotten huge.

I have looked around for log rotation, but could not find anything laravel 4 related. In laravel 5 there is a `log` option in the `config/app.php` which you can give values like `daily` etc. But I don't see any such option in laravel 4. https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v4.1.0/app/config/app.php

How can i acheive log rotation in laravel 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following lines of code in your app/start/global.php file.

```
$logFile = 'laravel.log';

Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path().'/logs/'.$logFile);
```

Comment: Got it, for me it was in the `app/start/global.php'. Any idea how to do weekly log rotation?

Comment: can you give me an idea about the weekly log rotation?